# MongoDB Schema Suggestion

Tags: mongodb, database-design

I am trying to pick MongoDB as my preferred database. I need help on the design of my table.

App background - analytics app where contacts push their own events and related custom data. Contact can have many events. Eg: contact did this, did that etc.

event_type, custom_data (json), epoch_time

eg: 
event 1: event_type: page_visited, custom-data: {url: pricing, referrer: google}, current_time
event 2: event_type: video_watched, custom-data: {url: video_link}, current_time
event 3: event_type: paid, custom_data: {plan:lite, price:35}

These events are custom and are defined by the user. Scalability is a concern.

These are the common use cases:

- give me a list of users who have come to pricing page in the last 7 days
- give me a list of users who watched the video and paid more than 50
- give me a list of users who have visited pricing, watched video but NOT paid at least 20

What's the best way to design my table? 
Is it a good idea to use embedded events in this case?

Answer (score 0):

In Mongo they are called collections and not tables, since the data is not rows/columns :)

(1) I'd make an Event collection and a Users collections

(2) I'd do 1 document per Event which has a userId in it.

(3) If you need realtime data you will want an index on what you want to query by (i.e. never do a scan over the whole collection).

(4) if there are things which are needed for reporting only, I'd recommend making a reporting node (i.e. a different mongo instance) and using replication to copy data to that mongo instance.  You can put additional indexes for reporting on that node.  That way the additional indexes and any expensive queries will not affect production performance.

*Notes on sharding*

If your events collection is going to become large - you may need to consider sharding.  Perhaps sharding by user Id.  However, I'd recommend that may be a longer term solution and not to dive into that until you need it.

One thing to note, is that mongo has currently (2.6) a database level write locking implementation.  Which means you can only perform 1 write at a time.  It allows many reads.  Which means that if you want a high write system AND have a lot of users, you will need to look into sharding at some point.  However, in my experience so far, administratively 1 primary node with a secondary (and reporting node) is easier to setup.  We currently can handle around 10,000 operations per second with that setup.

However, we have had issues with spikes in users coming to the system.  You'll want to make sure you have enough memory for your indexes.  And SSD's would be recommended to.  as a surge in users can result in cache misses (i.e. index not in memory) which causes it to be read off the hard disk.

One final note - there are a lot of NoSQL DB's and they all have their pros and cons.  I personally found that high write, low read, and realtime anaysis of lots of data is not really mongo's strength. So it does depend on what you are doing.  It sounds like you are still learning the fundamentals.  It might be worth a read of all the available types to pick the right tool for the right job.

Comment: Thanks for your note. What would you suggest for high writes, low reads and real time analysis?

Comment: If you are using AWS then DynamoDB is fast and may meet your event needs (primary key userId, with a range on date or event type).  Cassandra has some positive reviews (on the web and with people I work with).  I'm investigating a few other NoSQL DB's - most I can eliminate, although a few which I'm still midway through investigation which may/may not be good for you are Riak or Couchbase. (But I'd lean towards DynamoDB or Cassandra at the moment )

Comment: DynamoDB doesn't support nested JSON search. The custom data is totally different for each customer and they write their custom data.